# Modulo and Congruence Class Proof.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

> (A) Determine all the equivalence classes for the relation of congruence modulo $5$.
>
> (B) Give the partition $P$ of $ℤ$ associated with the relation of congruence modulo $5$.

In order to first due this proof I know that one must know what modulo is % which means the remainder. So I understand that one must find the first 4 partitions from $0$ to $1$. So this means that one must do that first modulo  remainder zero.

$$0=\{\dots ,-10,-5,0,5,10,\dots \}$$

This means that these are whole numbers and will leave $\color{red}{No}$ remainder so I get that. But where I get stuck at is when you have remainder $1$ then you get something like

$$1 = \{\dots ,11,\dots\}$$

Am I in the right track does one need to do a number n % 5 in order to to prove this relation.  How far does one go when does it end? Where is a good place to stop the relationship? Of the remainders of course.

Then partition is as

$ℤ = \{0, \dots, 4\}$ since they don't intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note if you divide an integer $n$ by $5$, the remainder must be less than $5$. The only possibilities for the remainder are $0,1,2,3,4$. So the equivalence classes are

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\{5n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\} &= \{\ldots,-10,-5,0,5,10,\ldots\}\\
\{5n + 1: n \in \mathbb{Z}\} &= \{\ldots,-9,-4,1,6,11,\ldots\}\\
\{5n + 2: n \in \mathbb{Z}\} &= \{\ldots,-8,-3,2,7,12,\ldots\}\\
\{5n + 3: n \in \mathbb{Z}\} &= \{\ldots,-7,-2,3,8,13,\ldots\}\\
\{5n + 4: n \in \mathbb{Z}\} &= \{\ldots,-6,-1,4,9,14,\ldots\}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
The partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ associated with the equivalence relation congruence modulo $5$ is simply the partition into the above equivalence classes.

Comment: If you are doing the remainder and you do -9 % 5 would you not get 4 for the remainder?

Comment: I understand why 11 is there but the other numbers not so much.

Comment: 11%5 is 1, I am not following the pattern.

Comment: So -9 =11 if you add it wont you get 20? Unless you do 11%-9 which is 2.mhhh...

Comment: $-9 = 5 \cdot (-2) + 1$, my mistake. Or alternatively, $5$ divides $-9 - 1 = -10$, so $-9 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.